# Error with sending SPL-TOKENS (NFT) using @solana/spl-token library

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, spl-token, nft, phantom

I have a problem with sending tokens. I need to send NFT from my Phantom wallet. Most likely the problem is with `Assosiated Token Account`, because somewhere in this process I catch errors. I'm trying to create an instruction for `ATA`, and add it to the transaction before executing the instruction to transfer the tokens (NFT)

Errors like this: `Error processing Instruction 2: Provided seeds do not result in a valid address`

```
                let receiverATA = await getAssociatedTokenAddress(mintAddress, receiverPublicKey);

            
                const destination = await createAssociatedTokenAccountIdempotentInstruction(
                        window.solana.publicKey, // presumably your wallet
                        receiverATA,
                        mintAddress,  // of the token you are sending
                        receiverPublicKey, // person you are sending the token to
                        TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
                        ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
                );
                transaction.add(destination);
                console.log("destination:", destination);
                
                


                await sleep(350);

                if (amount > 0) {
                    const transferInstruction = createTransferInstruction(
                        senderTokenAccountAddress, 
                        receiverATA,
                        senderPublicKey, 
                        amount * Math.pow(10, decimals),
                        [],
                        TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
                    );
                    transaction.add(transferInstruction);
                    await sleep(300);
                }
                
            }               


          transaction.feePayer = window.solana.publicKey;
          let blockhashObj = await connection.getRecentBlockhash();
          transaction.recentBlockhash = await blockhashObj.blockhash;
          
            
          const signed = await window.solana.signTransaction(transaction);

          let txid = await connection.sendRawTransaction(signed.serialize());
          await connection.confirmTransaction(txid);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The params are in the incorrect order for creating the associated-token-account, try doing:

```
                const destination = await createAssociatedTokenAccountIdempotentInstruction(
                        window.solana.publicKey, // presumably your wallet
                        receiverATA,
                        receiverPublicKey, // person you are sending the token to
                        mintAddress,  // of the token you are sending
                        TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
                        ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
                );
```

Source code at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/6366ad9b689a4139ec5ae70c180e0f08f750d0e3/token/js/src/instructions/associatedTokenAccount.ts#L48

Comment: Thanks i already did it. My fault. 
By the way maybe you can help me with it https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/10042/error-signature-verification-failed-thawaccount