# Error: Signature verification failed (ThawAccount)

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, spl-token, nft, signature

I'm trying to add `ThawAccountInstruction` to my main transaction but but I'm getting an error `Signature verification failed`.

I'm trying to unfreeze the frozen accounts (NFT) in my wallet and send them via transfer to another wallet. Without this instruction everything works correctly and the transaction is signed, but something is wrong here. For the freeze parameter I use the `Freeze Authority` public key.

I sign my transaction (one) at the end with Phantom (since I connect through it).

```
                const unfreeze = await createThawAccountInstruction (
                    senderTokenAccountAddress,
                    mintAddress,
                    freeze,
                    [],
                    TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
                );
                    transaction.add(unfreeze);
```

I signing like this:

```
          transaction.feePayer = window.solana.publicKey;
          
          let blockhashObj = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();
          transaction.recentBlockhash = await blockhashObj.blockhash;

          const signed = await window.solana.signTransaction(transaction);
          let txid = await connection.sendRawTransaction(signed.serialize());
          await connection.confirmTransaction(txid);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to sign with `freeze`, so most likely the keypair at `window.solana` is not the same as `freeze`.

You'll need to find a way to sign with `freeze`, either by providing a web service to sign transactions, or make the freeze authority public in some way.